# Is there anyway to make this code snippet more efficient?

Tags: java, loops

I am working on some code where I have this snippet

```
{

    user = "B";
    indice = 21;

    switch (user) {
        case "A":
            A[indice - 1] = "X";
            break;
        case "B":
            B[indice - 1] = "X";
            break;
        case "C":
            C[indice - 1] = "X";
            break;

    }

}
```

I was wondering if there is a possible way to make this code more efficiently so I don't have to rewrite it X ammount of times there could also be more values then the ammount of switch's I have setup, any help would be much advice would be a great help

Comment: Well, if your main concern isn't about performance, perhaps you could try using reflection.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here.  There are various ways to package things to make this more efficient, but doing so requires that we we know things about the A, B, and C arrays, and the nature of X, and whether the correspondence between the user value of "B" and the array B can be represented differently in a way that fits their use

Comment: yes, through reflection you can get the object's attribute dynamically, then you can assign a value to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `Map<String,String[]>`, put the arrays `A`, `B` and `C` in it, and then use this code:

```
Map<String,String[]> arrayByName = new HashMap<String,String[]>();
arrayByName.put("A", A);
arrayByName.put("B", B);
arrayByName.put("C", C);
...
arrayByName.get(user)[indice-1] = "X";
```

Comment: Thank you! hopefully I can implement this solution, many thanks.

Comment: If more efficient points to performance, this approach is much more slower than original solution. HasMap for three items is slower than sequence searching within simple array. Speaking of which, original solution used array directly so I dont think that it's possible to write better code.

Comment: I don't think performance is an issue with this code I'm writing as I'm just learning, but in order to do it the way I wrote, I would of had to have 3 switches all containing 12 cases thought maybe there was a better way to do it for learning experience, thanks for advice though!

Answer (score 2):

If the cases of your switch will always be consecutive (e.g. `"A", "B", "C"`) and will always be single-character, you could do something along the lines of

```
String[][] master = {A, B, C};

...

master[user.charAt(0) - 'A'][indice - 1] = "X";
```